# AngularJS different template based on User Agent

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, adaptive-design

I have a spring MVC app that spits out JSON. I am planning to use AngularJS as my front end and would want it to use different templates based on user agent (desktop/mobile). May I know is it doable using AngularJS? If so, how? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it myself, but I think this could work:

```
$scope.userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

<some-template ng-if="userAgent === 'firefox'">
<some-other-template ng-if="userAgent !== 'firefox'">
```

Have you tried using navigator.userAgent?

Another option I reckon would be to turn to ui-router and make use of its resolve function. Then run some navigator.userAgent lookup from a service, and decide on the correct template before rendering the view - reducing the amount of ng-if's.

This is just guesswork at this stage, give it a go and see what works / doesn't, good luck : )